# SQL Server with Service Broker

Tags: sql-server, service-broker

When I do something such as `insert`, `update` in SQL Server, and I have a Service Broker queue. I just know do `SEND` to send the message to the queue.

Q: can the message send to queue automatically? Thanks.

Comment: QueryNotification (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms130764.aspx) sends a message to a queue when the data changes.

Comment: In this method,we just know the operations,`update` or `delete` and so on,we do not konw which row haved changed. So I must select all rows to update the cache data,right?

Comment: Yes, Querynotification is not sufficient if you need more exact information on changes. In that case I would either combine it with change tracking or just have triggers sending the messages.

Comment: Triggers have be forbidden in this project.Change Tracking,I can have a try.Thanks

Comment: Change Tracking or CDC,which one is better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no built-in way of sending messages in response to changes to a table. You would have to wire this up yourself using triggers or forcing all your table changes to go via stored procedures.

Comment: Thanks.But how store procedures works? I can not use triggers in the database.And we also want to get the change automatically.Is there any methods do it without triggers.That is problem.

Comment: Essentially I do this: create read-only views over tables and the deny the users permission to directly use the tables. Then create an update, delete and insert procedure for each table and give the users permission on these. In each procedure you can log the event or post a message to a queue. I use a code generator to create the procedures so it only takes a minute to do a whole database.